# Is it possible to set ng-repeat to length of array plus one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a unique situation where I would like to present my users with a single input field initially. There would also be a 'plus' button to the right of this input which when clicked inserts another input field below, and so on, to allow the user to input an unknown number of parameters:

[image]

I would like to use an `ng-repeat` to accomplish this, but the following (obviously) does not show an input field because `parameters.values.length` is zero before any input is entered:

```
<div ng-if="parameter.repeatable" ng-repeat="value in parameter.values">
  <input name="parameter" type="text" ng-model="parameter.values">
    <button
      class="btn btn-xs btn-success"
      uib-tooltip="Add another parameter"
      tooltip-placement="top"
      ng-click="savedQueries.addRow()">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Note: `savedQueries.addRow()` currently does not do anything.

Thinking further, another option may be to automatically insert an input below the current input whenever text is entered in the current input field.

My questions are basically, how to set this `ng-repeat` up when the length of `parameter.values` is initially zero? Also, how to push this (unknown) number of values into an array? I'm thinking I would need to take advantage of `$index`.

Comment: Put an empty value as default in parameter.values

Comment: Do you *always* want the plus button on *every* element in the repeat? Seems like that'd be either a special case on the *last* element, or not part of the repeat at *all*.

Comment: @DaveNewton That's a very good point, I would only need that button after the last input field. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating it. Just have an array of values (or objects), and iterate over that. In the controller, add one default value. And whenever the plus button is pressed, push a new value to that array.

E.g

```
$scope.parameters = [""]; // array with one empty text element
$scope.newRow = function() {
    $scope.parameters.push(""); // add a new empty text element
}
```

and

```
<div ng-repeat="value in parameter">
  <input type="text" ng-model="value">
</div>
<button ng-click="newRow()">+</button>
```